# What is PHP7 error "not found or unable to stat"?

Tags: apache2, php7

I am receiving the following error log on my apache2 server:

`[Mon Dec 24 09:38:48.580631 2018] [php7:error] [pid 19547] [client 5.188.210.12:11267] script '/var/www/echo.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://www.google.com/
[Mon Dec 24 18:16:33.851584 2018] [php7:error] [pid 19523] [client 91.211.247.248:45013] script '/var/www/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Dec 25 03:28:48.912986 2018] [php7:error] [pid 19551] [client 185.244.25.106:47712] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Dec 25 04:15:30.013401 2018] [php7:error] [pid 19527] [client 118.25.71.119:37946] script '/var/www/help.php' not found or unable to stat`
I am sure that's just bruteforcing on existing scripts.
But how can this throw a PHP7 error?
What do the ports mean as I am not using any of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache passed the request to PHP because the URL ended in `.php` and Apache was configured to do so with an `AddHandler` directive.

The port number and IP address are of the remote system.

These are being logged because the PHP script corresponding to the URL does not exist or cannot be accessed. A 404 error is returned.

And yes, it looks like automated brute forcing attempts. You can ignore these or enable the relevant fail2ban jail.